# Anyone else getting their questions truncated?

Tags: support

I tried several times to post a question I have, but it kept getting severely truncated when I'd try to post it. Has anyone else run up against this?

As was wisely suggested, I pasted the raw text into pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/Cw07q7vs, but *lo and behold*, pastebin truncated it too! Have I used some magical character-combination that ends files?

Update: I fixed it, but I'm not entirely sure how. After a lot of trial and error, I ended up deleting and retyping the first line of block-quote (which was always the last line that would show up in my attempted posts). The *only* difference I can find is that the old (broken) version had *two* spaces after the `>` and the new (working) version has just *one*. Maybe that was the cause, but I'm afraid to mess with it now that it's working :P

Should I 'answer' this question, delete it, or just leave it for posterity?

Comment: There is a length limit, but it is so large that you would never notice it in normal use of the site. This is not the issue here. One thing I observe is that you begin every line of a quote with >.  Only the first line needs this character; Markdown interprets the rest of the paragraph as a quote. I doubt that this is what caused the problem, but who knows... Angle brackets are a sharp weapon. // Also, you should put your text into pastebin, so that others can experiment with it (in a sandbox, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since pastebin truncated the text at the same place, the issue was probably caused by an invisible character at the end of the line `>  $$a^{m/n} = \left(\sqrt[n]{a}\right)^m$$`.

> Having two spaces after `>` is not a problem. (This is an example.)

Comment: I'm prepared to take your word on this :)

Comment: It could not be anything but speculation... unless you still have a copy of the original post and can put it somewhere that does not truncate.

Comment: yeah, I think I trashed the original already.